# How to convert a command output from a string to an integer?

Tags: python, time

I have a script that uses the `time` module in Python to get the current time in hours, minutes and seconds and store them in three different variables:

```
import time

while True:
     A = time.strftime("%H")
     B = time.strftime("%M")
     C = time.strftime("%S")
```

I want to be able to do some math with these numbers, but they are always interpreted as strings.

```
A = "07"
B = "58"
C = "27"
```

How can I convert the string output of the command into a number that I can do math with? Whenever I try to multiply them like they are numbers I get outputs like `"70707070707070707070707"`.

Comment: If you want a number, why on earth are you using `strftime`?! And what's with `while True`?

Comment: you should use `dt = datetime.utcnow()` to get the current time as a naive datetime object representing time in UTC. To get hours, minutes, seconds as integers just use the corresponding attributes: `dt.hour`, `dt.minute`, `dt.second`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

while True:
     A = int(time.strftime("%H"))
     B = int(time.strftime("%M"))
     C = int(time.strftime("%S"))

     # K=A*2+B*3+C*4
```